# customizing cd command

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, cd

Generally I keep directory specific settings in `.bashrc` and whenever I change directory execute the command `source .bashrc` to make those settings effective.
 Now I was thinking of manipulating cd command in `~/.bashrc`, so  whenever I cd to new directory and if any .bashrc exists there, it will be loaded automatically.

Similar to this `cd $1; source .bashrc` ( I have verified that $1 is valid path), but problem is cd is shell builting, so it's a recursive loop ( cd always points to modifed cd ). We do not have elf file of cd ( which generally we have of other commands viz scp or others). So how can I achieve this ?
 Also if `shopt -s cdspell` is supported then also I need to have cd spelled path in argument of $1.

Comment: Why People are closing it ? Is this duplicate to some other thread , I don't think so. Or because of people having 100K or 900K reputation couldn't get chance to answer it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the "builtin" command;

> builtin shell-builtin [arguments]
>
> Execute the specified shell builtin,
>   passing it arguments, and return its exit status. This is useful when
>   defining a function whose name is the same as a shell builtin,
>   retaining the functionality of the builtin within the function. The cd
>   builtin is commonly redefined this way. The return status is false if
>   shell-builtin is not a shell builtin command.

From: http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

So, you could have something like (untested, don't have a bash handy either);

```
function cd() {
    builtin cd $1 \
        && test -e .bashrc \
        && source .bashrc
}
```

Comment: probably should check success of `cd`: `builtin cd "$1" && test -e .bashrc && source .bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

You might check out direnv. https://github.com/zimbatm/direnv

Comment: One of the specific goals when I designed direnv was to avoid overriding builtin commands as RVM does (did?). Instead direnv depends on shell hooks like PROMPT_COMMAND in bash to detect directory changes.

Answer (score 1):

[RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) does this:

```
$ type cd
cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    if builtin cd "$@"; then
        [[ -n "${rvm_current_rvmrc:-}" && "$*" == "." ]] && rvm_current_rvmrc="" || true;
        __rvm_do_with_env_before;
        __rvm_project_rvmrc;
        __rvm_after_cd;
        __rvm_do_with_env_after;
        return 0;
    else
        return $?;
    fi
}
```

And yes, this works on my machine. Essentially, as @RoryHunter said, use `builtin` and run some code if it succeeds, or return the exit code if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
function cdd(){ cd $1; if [ -e ./.bashrc ] ; then source ./.bashrc; fi; }
alias cd = 'cdd' 
?
```

Didn't tested this much, however.

Comment: problem is same, recursive call to this new definition of cd.

Comment: I've tested this in the following variant:

 function cdd(){
  cd $1;
  if [ -e ./.bashrc ]; then echo "Hi, there!"; fi
 }
 alias cd='cdd'

Then 
  prompt> cd 
  Hi, there